# Count the number of nested field values that appear in documents with two specific values in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a number of documents in ElasticSearch database, that look like this:

Document 1:

```
{
    “Id”: 6000,
    “customerName”: GT, 
    “pages”: [
    {
    “fieldType”: typeA,
    “fieldId”: 1001
    }
    {
    “fieldType”: typeB,
    “fieldId”: 1002
    }
]
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
    “Id”: 6001,
    “customerName”: MX, 
    “pages”: [
    {
    “fieldType”: typeA,
    “fieldId”: 1001
    }
    
]
}
```

Document 3:

```
{
    “Id”: 6002,
    “customerName”: MX, 
    “pages”: [
    {
    “fieldType”: typeB,
    “fieldId”: 1002
    }
    {
    “fieldType”: typeC,
    “fieldId”: 1003
    }
]
}
```

Document 4:

```
{
    “Id”: 6003,
    “customerName”: GT, 
    “pages”: [
    {
    “fieldType”: typeA,
    “fieldId”: 1005
    }
    {
    “fieldType”: typeC,
    “fieldId”: 1003
    }
]
}
```

Document 5:

```
{
    “Id”: 6004,
    “customerName”: MX, 
    “pages”: [
    {
    “fieldType”: typeA,
    “fieldId”: 1005
    }
]
}
```

I need to count the number of typeA entries that are nested within “pages” field, but only those that appear in both documents - those with customerName GT and MX. Basically, I want to find how many times typeA is shared between the documents where customerName=GT and customerName=MX.

So, that means I would count 2 of typeA entries - one with fieldId 1001 that is in Document 1 and Document 2, and other with fieldId 1005 that is in Document 4 and Document 5.
How can I do this using DSL query?

So far, I tried this which returns the result that counts for either GT or MX, not for both :

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
      {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "customerName": "CN"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customerName": "MX"
          }
        }
      ]
      {
         "nested": {
           "path": "pages",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "fieldType": "typeA"
                     }
                   }
                }
              }  
           }
         }
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75111613/18778181) to this question. You have the groups types to each documents with customerName GT or MX.

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "customerName": "GT"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customerName": "MX"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_customer_name": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "pages"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_field_type": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "pages.fieldType.keyword",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
      "aggregations": {
    "agg_customer_name": {
      "doc_count": 8,
      "agg_field_type": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "typeA",
            "doc_count": 4
          },
          {
            "key": "typeB",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "typeC",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rabbitbr but I don't think this is the answer I'm looking for. I want to count only those typeA values that appear both in document with customerName=GT and with customerName=MX (in the case above that would give 2 - (Doc 1 and Doc 2) and (Doc 4 and Doc5).  I guess one way would be to first find all typeA fields that belong to customerName with GT and then have another run when I check of these fields belong to MX. But I don't see how to do that in one DSL query.

Comment: you don't want the key "type" and "type c" in the bucket?

Comment: no, I want to count only typeA that appears in two document (customerName=GT) AND (customerName=MX). So, I don't want to count typeA if it appears in only   (customerName=GT) OR (customerName=MX)