# Count the number of times a filed value is shared between the documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

How can I count the number of times where one field with a certain value appears in TWO documents where another field takes two values in ElasticSearch?

For example, if my document looks like this:

```
{ “Id”: 6000,
 “customerName”: CN,
 “customerValue”: 10 }
```

```
{ “Id”: 6001,
 “customerName”: MX, 
“customerValue”: 10 }
```

I want to count by DSL query that customerValue field of value 10 appeared once in BOTH the first document where customerName = CN and the second document where customerName = MX.
I basically want to count the number of times customerValue is SHARED between the documents where customerName is CN and MX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below filter docs with customer name CN or MX.
The aggs groups customerValue and the results show number docs with value equals 10.

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "customerName": "CN"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customerName": "MX"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_customer_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customerValue",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
  "aggregations": {
"agg_customer_name": {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": 10,
      "doc_count": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @rabbitbr! This is actually a part of a more complex question, where I need to combine this with search in nested field. But when I combine this "should" statement with the nested search in a "must" statement, I don't get the right result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101587/count-the-number-of-nested-field-values-that-appear-in-documents-with-two-specif.